# Bitnami Artifactory Installation on Ubuntu 14.04 machine is not working

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, artifactory, bitnami

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 machine and need to install Bitnami Artifactory on it. I followed the procedure below:

1) Login to Ubuntu machine.

2) Install virtual box with apt-get command as `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`.

3) Once this is successful, I downloaded Bitnami Artifactory .ova file from the bitnami site and imported using VBoxManage commands.

4) VBoxManage import bitnami-artifactory-4.9.0-0-linux-ubuntu-14.04-x86_64.ova --vsys 0 --ostype "Ubuntu_64" --vmname afactory_vm --cpus 1 --memory 8000

VBoxManage showvminfo artifactory_vm

VBoxManage registervm /home/cluster/VirtualBox\ VMs/afactory_vm/afactory_vm.vbox

VBoxManage startvm afactory_vm --type headless

VBoxManage list runningvms

VBoxManage hostonlyif create

VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 192.168.56.1

VBoxManage dhcpserver modify --ifname vboxnet0 —enable

5) I did some network setup as mentioned in the URL https://2buntu.com/articles/1513/accessing-your-virtualbox-guest-from-your-host-os/

6) I am not able to access this virtual machine from external network either with 192.168.25.100 , 192.168.25.101 or 192.168.56.1

Can anyone please suggest me how can I setup a VM and obtain access from the external network?

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Developer here

VirtualBox has several networking modes. Some of them are:

**Host-only networking**

This can be used to create a network containing the host and a set of virtual machines, without the need for the host's physical network interface. Instead, a virtual network interface (similar to a loopback interface) is created on the host, providing connectivity among virtual machines and the host.

**Network Address Translation (NAT)**

If you want to browse the Web or download files inside the virtual machine, then this default mode should be sufficient for you.

**Bridged networking**

When enabled, VirtualBox connects to one of your installed network cards and exchanges network packets directly, circumventing your host operating system's network stack.

If you need to access your guest from outside, you need to configure bridged networking. This mode will give your virtual machine its own IP in your local network.

Comment: right click on VM and select settings->Network, I selected Bridged Network in Adapter tab and tried to connect with IP 192.168.56.101 (which is displayed after login to VM) but no luck. i am getting connecting timed out error. can you please tell me if i need to do any settings in VirtuaBox or VM.